# Problem with CORS. Google directions API GET request | vue.js

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vuejs2, map-directions

I currently work on vue.js project.
The app goal is to check distance between 2 localisations, then show route on the map and calculate cost of transport which is based on the distance.

I use google directions api, axios for get request.

Problem is that, because of CORS, get request gives me an error (I run this app locally).
I already tried chrome CORS plugin, but problem still exists.

[image: error screenshot]

Do You have any solutions or just idea how to solve this problem?

Thank You in advance.

P.S.
Code below

```
import axios from 'axios';

const directionsApi = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?';
const apiKey = '&key=trust_me_the_key_is_valid';

export default {
  name: 'FirstForm',
  data() {
    return {
      fromValue: '',
      toValue: '',
      distance: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFromToInput: function () {
      const fromTo = `origin=${this.fromValue}&destination=${this.toValue}`;
      axios.get(`${directionsApi}${fromTo}${apiKey}`)
        .then((response) => {
          // this.distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
          console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Looks like you have to use the Google Maps JavaScript SDK instead of doing plain HTTP requests: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/issues/59#issuecomment-399626833

Does that help you?

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript SDK? What do You mean?
How could I get distance between two points just using normal javascript api?
I have switched to distance matrix api and "postman" gives me pretty json with whole data I need. Problem still exist in vue app.

Comment: Why not use [VueGoogleMaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) package?

Answer (score 3):

[Similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185061/google-places-api-cors)

If you use Javascript API way to do,

1. Create an account on Google Maps Platform
2. Open Vue Project
3. Make a js file (src/utils/gmap.js)

```
// src/utils/gmaps.js
const API_KEY = 'XXXXXYOURAPIKEYXXXX';
const CALLBACK_NAME = 'gmapsCallback';

let initialized = !!window.google;
let resolveInitPromise;
let rejectInitPromise;
const initPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolveInitPromise = resolve;
  rejectInitPromise = reject;
});

export default function init() {
  if (initialized) return initPromise;

  initialized = true;
  window[CALLBACK_NAME] = () => resolveInitPromise(window.google);

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;
  script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${API_KEY}&callback=${CALLBACK_NAME}`;
  script.onerror = rejectInitPromise;
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);

  return initPromise;
}
```

4. In view js (src/views/MyMap.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="my-map">
      My Map
      <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import gmapsInit from '@/utils/gmaps';
export default {
  name: 'myMap',
  components: {
  },
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      const google = await gmapsInit();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
  methods:{
  }

}
</script>

<style>
#map{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
</style>
```

Ref on

[Using the Google Maps API with Vue.js](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/using-the-google-maps-api-with-vue/)

[Maps JavaScript API, Hello World](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. Maybe it's not best but it works.

I've used cors-anywhere proxy.

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${directionsApi}${fromTo}${apiKey}
```